# Quickly creating certain files in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an easy and quick way to create certain files in VS Code as in full blown Visual Studio? For example, I can create a config file or an app settings json file in Visual Studio that will not only create the file but insert the basic structure into the file.

Is this possible in VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done in bare Visual Studio Code. But there's a couple of extensions around which do what you are looking for.

Here's a non-exhaustive list of extensions:

- [File Templates for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bam.vscode-file-templates)
- [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brpaz.file-templates)
- ...